# jQuery show/hide table rows based on cell content

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to make some Javascript that shows/hides rows in a data table based on the content of the 4th cell.

Table is as follows:

```
DATE | DESCRIPTION | PRICE | PHONE |  STATUS  |
-----------------------------------------------
xxx  | yyyyyyyyyyy | 3243  | 32553 | Finished |
xxx  | yyyyyyyyyyy | 3243  | 32553 | Suspeded |
xxx  | yyyyyyyyyyy | 3243  | 32553 | Active   |
xxx  | yyyyyyyyyyy | 3243  | 32553 | Finished |
```

And I have the following code on the onChange function of a dropdown:

```
function refinesearch() {
    $(".data tr").hide(); //hide all rows
    var refine = $("#refine1").val(); //retrieve wanted status

    if(refine=="All") {
        $(".data tr").show(); //show all rows if want to see All
    } else {

        $(".data tr").each(function() { //loop over each row

             if($("td:eq(4)").text() == refine) { //check value of TD
                 $(this).show(); //show the row 

             }

        });

    }
}
```

Basically, the dropdown has the different statuses in, and if they selected, e.g Finished only the rows that have the status Finished should be shown and all others hidden.

But it doesn't seem to be working correctly. When I select All it works and when I select Finished it shows them all for some reason! Selecting any other value makes all rows hidden! :S - any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - thanks for the help Paul!

```
function refinesearch() {

    var count = 1;
    $(".data tr").hide(); //hide all rows
    $(".data tr:first").show();
    $(".data tr:nth-child(2)").show();

    var refine = $("#refine1").val(); //retrieve wanted status
    if(refine=="All") {
        $(".data tr").show(); //show all rows if want to see All
    } else {

        $(".data tr").each(function() { //loop over each row

            if($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text() == refine) { //check value of TD

                $(this).find("td").css({"background": "#fff", "border-right" : "none"});
                $(this).show(); //show the row 

            }

        });

        $(".data tr:visible").each(function() { //loop over each row

            if(isEven(count)) {
                $(this).find("td").css({"background" : "#D4EDF9", "border-right" : "3px solid #D4EDF9" });
            }

            count++;

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your loop `$("td:eq(4)")` is selecting table cell in the whole page (not only the row in the loop).

You can still do this:

```
$(".data tr").toggle(function() {
  return refine == "All" || $("td:eq(4)", this).text() == refine;
})
```

instead of your whole `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the find() method to restrict your criteria to the current row (yours is selecting all the rows in the table on each loop):

```
function refinesearch() {
    $(".data tr").hide(); //hide all rows
    var refine = $("#refine1").val(); //retrieve wanted status

    if(refine=="All") {
        $(".data tr").show(); //show all rows if want to see All
    } else {

        $(".data tr").each(function() { //loop over each row

             if($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text() == refine) { //check value of TD
                 $(this).show(); //show the row 

             }

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: This did it! However it does hide the header row too - any simple way to avoid this? I addition, I have CSS that colours every other row background. Hiding rows obviously screws this, is there any way to 'regenerate' this fill? Cheers.

Comment: You could add an index and increment it each loop.  Then always show the row if 'i==1' (header row).  For the row colors, use an the 'nth child' selector in a style sheet http://davidwalsh.name/css-tables-css3-alternate-row-colors

Comment: Okay - I've got the header working and think I'm near with the CSS but can't figure out the right selector. I have http://pastebin.com/HkiEeMTC but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".newgrid tbody tr td:nth-child(5)").each(function () {

                    var found = false;
                    for (i = 0; i < selected.length && !found; i++) {
                        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(selected[i].toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found)
                        $(this).parent().hide();
                    else
                        $(this).parent().show();

                });
```

This will do the trick. selected is an array contains what are the possible td values you going to check. If it's just a string, you can replace the array for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop over each row you miss `$(this)` to refer to your current element.
Then, use find() to filter the selection
`$(this).find("td:eq(4)").text() == refine`