# JQuery show table row if value found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This might seem similar to other questions, and I have found and read through those questions and tried them, but I haven't gotten a working solution as of course, my code is unique and I need maybe another set of eyes to help me find my bug.

Anyway, the problem:

I'm creating a table (with PHP), and essentially if a cell has a value, the row gets an id of 'foo' and is hidden (using CSS - display: none;), and when I click a checkbox I'm trying to display all those hidden rows.

```
<tr id='foo'><td>this row is hidden</td></tr>
<tr><td>this row is not hidden</td></tr>
```

My jQuery is currently this:

```
$("#showHiddenRows").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("showing"); //This pops up
        $("#tableName").each(function() {
            if($("#tableName").find("tr").attr("id") === 'foo') {
                $("#tableName").find("tr").attr("style", "display: initial;");
                alert("found a hidden row"); //This does not pop up...
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("hiding");
        //essentially the same code here, but display:none;
    }
```

So I added alerts as you can see, the "showing" and "hiding" alerts pop up, but the "found a hidden row" doesn't, implying that searching through my table doesn't find any rows with an ID of 'foo', and I'm not sure why. Is there a better way to do this/is this the best way, and if so what did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Quick explanation of what I was intending the code to do:

- Loop through each row in the tableName table
- If you find a tablerow with an ID of 'foo', show or hide the row.

Comment: sidenote: `id` attribute values are supposed to be unique. use a `class=""` instead

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I was having heaps of issues as I'm also dealing with the DataTables JQuery plugin, which was applying classes after my code, and messing with it. I found it a lot easier to use `id=` and let DataTables do what it needed to `class`

Comment: DataTables jQuery plugin don't mess up things, but if you have problems using class try using some other attribute, like `tag = 'foo'` and use `attr("tag") == 'foo'`. Try using `==` instead of `===`. You may end up in more trouble than solving some with using duplicate ids.

Comment: You may also be interested in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385343/jquery-show-hide-table-rows-based-on-cell-content

Comment: I have some CSS attributed to the ID, like background colours and things. Unfortunately the `==` instead of `===` didn't fix it :(

Comment: @bansi I found that link before posting, that's where I got most of this code :) Unfortunately I must have adapted it too much, because it doesn't want to work for me.

Comment: @bansi === is perfectly fine. I think your problem is the .find("tr").attr("id") part. You should loop through all elements by using the .each function. I haven't tested it yet since I'm on my smartphone.

Comment: @bansi is right, you should avoid IDs if you are searching multiple items. **[I tried your code here](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/veL1vbfm/)** with classes instead of IDs and it runs just fine... I also **[tried it again](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/3dzkgjx9/1/)** using `.each()` instead of `.find()`, and again it runs fine

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm also using DataTables JQuery plugin which for whatever reason is messing with my classes when I apply them, as it applies classes after the document loads (client-side). I ended up using `id=` because it was working perfectly.

Comment: I also ended up with much less lines using the solutions below, rather than this searching row-by-row stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use **duplicate IDs**; use a CSS class instead. By definition, IDs should be unique; therefore no two or more elements should have the same ID.

**HTML:**

```
<tr class='foo'><td>this row is hidden</td></tr>
<tr><td>this row is not hidden</td></tr>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#showHiddenRows").on('change', function() {
        if( this.checked ) {
            $('table tr.foo').show();
        } else {
            $('table tr.foo').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

[**Or, you could shorten it like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/q1soo067/http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/q1soo067/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#showHiddenRows").on('change', function() {
        $('table tr.foo')[ this.checked ? 'show' : 'hide' ]();
    });
});
```

Comment: Should table be tableName, or is this being applied to all tables? 
e.g. `$('#tableName tr:hidden').show();`

Comment: Can you show the HTML of the table tag so I can use the correct table selector. I am more comfortable using `#tableID` (`<table id='tableID'...` instead of `#tableName` ... which sounds like `<table name="tableName" ...`

Comment: I adapted your code a little bit because as I mentioned in the comments, I needed to use ID. Posting my answer (but accepted yours, thanks!)

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

using non-unqiue id with jQuery will cause issues, but I'll leave that with you

here is what you should do to `show` hidden rows.

```
$("#showHiddenRows").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#tableName").each(function() {
        var table = $(this);
        var hiddenRows = table.find("tr[id=foo]").show();
        if(hiddenRows.length)
          alert("found " + hiddenRows.length + " hidden rows");
      });
    } else {
       alert("hiding");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with (thanks to user3558931):

```
$(function() {
    $("#tableName").on('change', function() {
        if($(this).(":checked")) {
            $('#tableName tr#foo').show();
        } else {
            $('#tableName tr#foo').hide();
        }
    });
});
```